# LCD that can be controlled via serial?

Tags: serial, lcd, rs232

I am very new to hobby electronics, but I was hoping I could find a way to get an LCD (preferably a backlit monochrome LCD with a grid of pixels -- something like [this](http://www.densitron.com/displays/content.aspx?id=2016)) that I could somehow mount in one of my computer's 5.25" drive bay and control via serial or something. What kind of LCD and other components could I get that could be controlled like this?

Comment: Lots. Lots and lots and lots.

Comment: Anyway, you could use a microcontroller to interface to the LCD. PC talks to µC, µC talks to LCD.

Comment: Or just get one that talks USB.

Comment: You can build one yourself (microcontroller + some programming work), or buy a ready made product that does this. But were are explicitly NOT a 'shopping recommendation' site, so you will have to do the googling yourself. I tried the 2 obvious searches and got both a serial and an USB version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one nice Graphical (it's a grid of pixels) LCD which Sparkfun sells (Open-Source hardware):

[image: LCD1][image: LCD2][image: LCD3]

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9351

Quoting the [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/Monochrome/Corrected-SFE-0016-DataSheet-08884-SerialGraphicLCD-v2.pdf):

> Setting up the display is as easy as connecting 6V to 
>   Vin, 0V to GND and a serial TX line from your source 
>   to the RX line on the backpack

For other options you can go [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/search/results?term=serial%20lcd). I didn't bother to look outside Sparkfun, but I'm sure you can find other options.